# what happen to Reducer while Map operation sends non key value as an output in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop

Map operation generally take input as key and value pair. and it will return same key and value pair as output. If map will return non key-value pair output, that time how Reducer will process that output.

Please any one assist on this would be appreciated

Comment: what is a 'non key-value pair output`?

Comment: are you talking about their types or their actual values?

Comment: Are you asking what happens in the Reducer if the Mapper outputs no values?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Java MapReduce, but in Hadoop Streaming if the mappers do not produce any output the reducers will not be run.

You can test it by creating 2 small python scripts:

A mapper that simply consumes the input without producing anything

```
#!/usr/bin/python
input()
```

A reducer that crashes as soon at it is started

```
#!/usr/bin/python
sys.exit("some error message")
```

If you launch it, the MapReduce job will complete without any error